# Olingo - Create strongly typed POJOs for client library of OData service

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I'm using Apache Olingo as an OData client for a Java SDK that I will provide for a RESTful OData API. In the SDK I want to be able to have strongly typed classes to represent the OData entities.  I'm having trouble implementing this easily and thus feel like I'm missing a different strategy here.

The Olingo way seems to be to get an `ODataClient` object which provides the user with a bunch of useful methods for interacting with the API. The `ODataClient` is using a bunch of factory methods to build my request.  For instance, this is the code I used to get the `Customers` from the Northwind sample OData service. `client` is an an instance of the necessary `ODataClient` class.

```
String serviceRoot = "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc";
URI customersUri = client.newURIBuilder(serviceRoot)
        .appendEntitySetSegment("Customers").build();
ODataRetrieveResponse<ODataEntitySetIterator<ODataEntitySet, ODataEntity>> response =
        client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntitySetIteratorRequest(customersUri).execute();

if (response.getStatusCode() >= 400) {
    log("Error");
    return;
}

ODataEntitySetIterator<ODataEntitySet, ODataEntity> iterator = response.getBody();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ODataEntity customer = iterator.next();
    log(customer.getId().toString());
}
```

I'd like to end up with a strongly typed entity from the iterator (i.e. `Customer customer = iterator.next()`).  However, I'm not sure how to actually do that.

If I create a `Customer` class that extends `ODataEntity` and attempt to perform a cast such as `Customer customer = (Customer) iterator.next()` then I get a `ClassCastException` since the objects in the iterator are just `ODataEntity` objects and know nothing about the `Customer` subclass.

My next thought was to introduce generics but doing so will require what seems like a good amount of modification to the Olingo library which leads me to think that there is a better way to do this.

I'm using the development version of Apache Olingo 4 since the OData service must use OData 4.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

It is not really advertised, but there is nowadays a POJO generator in Olingo, in the [source tree](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=olingo-odata4.git) at ext / pojogen-maven-plugin. Unfortunately for using the POJOs another layer with a different programming model is added, which holds entities cached in memory and syncs with OData service on a flush operation. I would be really interested in adapting it to a more conventional request/response model based on Olingos Request Factories.

However, you could try it out. In your pom include pojogen-maven-plugin and odata-client-proxy.
The POJO generation can be triggered in the pom with

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>pojogen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
            <localEdm>${basedir}/src/main/resources/metadata.xml</localEdm>
            <basePackage>odata.test.pojo</basePackage>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>v4pojoGen</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>v4pojoGen</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

For the experiment I stored the EDM Metadataof the Olingo Car example service at src/main/resources/metadata.xml. Somehow the plugin wants to create an inbetween ojc-plugin folder and I just moved the generated Java code at the proper place manually.

At that point you have a Service.java and Java interfaces for each entity or complex type in the EDM model.

You can make use of it to read some entities like this

```
Service<EdmEnabledODataClient> service = odata.test.pojo.Service.getV4("http://localhost:9080/odata-server-sample/cars.svc");
Container container = service.getEntityContainer(Container.class);
for (Manufacturer m : container.getManufacturers()) {
    System.out.println(m.getName());
}
```

Comment: The plugin does not work with the service metadata I am attempting to use - has it been tested with complex .Net service metadata?

Comment: I created a JIRA to address this @ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-885

Comment: sorry, but I cant find any docs on this anywhere, so... do you know if this pojo generator also works for odata v2 metadata?