# How can I consume an OData4 service in Java using either Olingo or the SDL OData Framework

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I need to consume an OData4 service from Java and based on the list of frameworks on the [OData website](http://www.odata.org/libraries/) the two choices are [Olingo](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/index.html) or the [SDL Odata Framework](https://github.com/sdl/odata).  My problem is that the documentation for both of these projects are focused on writing a service not consuming one.  The Olingo site links to a blog post from 2014 which is not API compatible with the current version and I couldn't find anything on the SDL github pages.

If someone could just provide me with a simple POST / GET example with using a proper POJO object model that would be great.

My limited understanding is that OData moves any information about the actual object model from compile time to runtime on the client.  I am happy to ignore this and code against a fixed object model because the service we are using won't change.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation of client side API seems to be a bit neglected by Olingo.
But there is an example in the [GIT repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=olingo-odata4.git) at samples / client.

Basically for a GET you do the following:

```
String serviceUrl = "http://localhost:9080/odata-server-sample/cars.svc"
String entitySetName = "Manufacturers";

ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient();
URI absoluteUri = client.newURIBuilder(serviceUri).appendEntitySetSegment(entitySetName).build();
ODataEntitySetIteratorRequest<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity> request = 
client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntitySetIteratorRequest(absoluteUri);
// odata4 sample/server limitation not handling metadata=full
request.setAccept("application/json;odata.metadata=minimal");
ODataRetrieveResponse<ClientEntitySetIterator<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity>> response = request.execute(); 
ClientEntitySetIterator<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity> iterator = response.getBody();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     ClientEntity ce = iterator.next();
     System.out.println("Manufacturer name: " + ce.getProperty("Name").getPrimitiveValue());
}
```

Have a look at the sample in the Olingo code base to get further details how to
retrieve metadata, process all properties etc.

To do a POST you can do as follows. (Note this is not tested code and the sample Car service is read-only.)
First you build up data as ClientEntity. You do e.g. with

```
ClientComplexValue manufacturer = of.newComplexValue("Manufacturer");
manufacturer.add(of.newPrimitiveProperty("Name", of.newPrimitiveValueBuilder().buildString("Ford")));
```

Then you send the POST request

```
ODataEntityCreateRequest<ClientEntity> request = client.getCUDRequestFactory().getEntityCreateRequest(absoluteUri, manufacturer);
ODataEntityCreateResponse<ClientEntity> response = request.execute();
```

So this is not with POJO classes - the result type is ClientEntity, which presents the data as name/value maps.
There is already another unanswered question about that particular topic at
[Olingo - Create strongly typed POJOs for client library of OData service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481630/olingo-create-strongly-typed-pojos-for-client-library-of-odata-service)
and I suggest that we turn there to follow up on that.

Comment: With odata-client-core version 4.0.0-beta-01: ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getV4(); (or xxx.getV3())

Answer (score 1):

For [SDL OData framework](https://github.com/sdl/odata), you can check this [Github Test class](https://github.com/sdl/odata/blob/master/odata_client/src/test/java/com/sdl/odata/client/DefaultODataClientTest.java) on how to use OData client.

SDL OData framework is based on the EDM classes and a simple example to get all Products (Product Edm Entity) will look like

```
// Create and configure the client
DefaultODataClient client = new DefaultODataClient();
client.configure(componentsProvider);

//Build the query
ODataClientQuery query = new BasicODataClientQuery.Builder().withEntityType(Product.class).build();

//Execute the query
List<Object> entities = (List<Object>) client.getEntities(requestProperties, query);
```