# Odata ClientEntity Error - Expected OData Entity, found EntitySet

Tags: java

I'm trying to use Olingo to connect to an Odata v4 service
I've tested it with the Northwind sample and the URI that gets produce works in a browser:

I always get the following

```
error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:org.apache.olingo.commons.api.serialization.ODataDeserializerException:
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Expected OData Entity, found
EntitySet.
```

**Code**

```
ODataEntityRequest<ClientEntity> reqEntity = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntityRequest(entityURI);
                ODataRetrieveResponse<ClientEntity> entity = reqEntity.execute();
            ClientEntity ce = (ClientEntity)entity.getBody();
```

at last line i am getting error.

```
ClientEntity ce = (ClientEntity)entity.getBody();
```

Comment: Refer below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297844/how-can-i-consume-an-odata4-service-in-java-using-either-olingo-or-the-sdl-odata

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are querying a collection URL like [http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories](http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$format=json). The response for this is the *EntitySet*.

However, seems that you want a single *Entity*. It can be got from the URL like [http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories(1)](http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories(1)?$format=json), where **(1)** corresponds with the ID of the Category you want to get.

2 options:

- If you want a single *Entity*, create a proper URI, e.g. `ODataClientFactory.getClient().newURIBuilder("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc").appendEntitySetSegment("Categories").appendKeySegment(1).build()` and execute a request on this (I think you can even skip the casting thing)
- If you want *EntitySet*, go for `getEntitySetRequest` against your uri and then use `getBody().getEntities()` on the result of the `execute()` method