# Apache Olingo pojogen

Tags: java, apache, odata, olingo

We're trying the Apache Olingo pojogen solution with OData V4. From a look into the generated code, it doesn't seem that it's thread-safe. Does anybody know of a possible solution to use the service and entity containers in a concurrent context?

Thanks!

Comment: Greetings! Did you manage to achieve something with the pojogenerator and do you mind sharing? I still don't know what it does, because the documentation is great, but I am looking to generate entity types and sets from pojos.

Comment: Hi, I've added the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to Alex comment:

yes we started exploring it but after sometime we decided to leave it. Main reasons:

1/ it failed to parse our Microsoft CRM metadata and we had to tweak the metadata manually to get pojogen to generate the Java pojos

2/ it does not seem to support concurrency. The pojogen Maven plugin generates a container which you can use to query your odata service. The container buffers your calls then you have to call a 'flush' method to flush to your odata service. However, the container you receive is a singleton and there's no way to flush only the calls from the current thread.

3/ There's not enough documentation/resources and the community seems to be very small.

You can start from this thread as I did:

[Olingo - Create strongly typed POJOs for client library of OData service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481630/olingo-create-strongly-typed-pojos-for-client-library-of-odata-service)

Comment: Thank you for the provided info... The documentation is awful and every bit of information is valuable. I didn't realize that the pojogen is client related, but learned something new.. Thank you for the effort!